# Como criar um container para abrir outras telas em flutter

Tags: flutter, flexdashboard

Preciso de ajudar para que os container abram outra tela, estou fazendo um menu Dashboard em flutter.

```
body: GridView.count (
          crossAxisCount: 3,
          children:[
            Container(
              color: Colors.blueGrey[100],
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: const [
                  Icon(Icons.home, color: Colors.black,),
                  Text("Home", style:TextStyle(color: Colors.black))
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Você só precisa colocar seu *Container* dentro de um *InkWell*, que vai permitir que seu container seja clicavel.

> Obs.: Utilizei a navegação padrão do Flutter, caso esteja usando rotas
> nomeadas faça os ajustes necessários.

```
InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const TelaQueDeveSerAberta()),
        );
      },
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.blueGrey[100],
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: const [
            Icon(
              Icons.home,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            Text("Home", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Comment: Já resolvi amigo, obg